# Parallel algorithm to compute Prefix Sum

Tags: algorithm, prefix-sum

I am having a problem with implementing the algorithm for computing a prefix sum in parallel. Even though this algorithm has 3 steps, I am unable to write the code, as no pseudo-code is given.

I went through various material on the web and also on stack overflow, but I didn't get the exact implementation of the algorithm as given on the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum). The wiki mentions the following:

> A prefix sum can be calculated in parallel by the following steps::
>
> 1. Compute the sums of consecutive pairs of items in which the first item of the pair has an even index: z0 = x0 + x1, z1 = x2 + x3, etc.
> 2. Recursively compute the prefix sum w0, w1, w2, ... of the sequence z0, z1, z2, ...
> 3. Expand each term of the sequence w0, w1, w2, ... into two terms of the overall prefix sum: y0 = x0, y1 = w0, y2 = w0 + x2, y3 = w1, etc. After the first value, each successive number yi is either copied from a position half as far through the w sequence, or is the previous value added to one value in the x sequence

Can someone please suggest a pseudo-code implementation for me to check and implement?

Comment: Isn't this a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053629/parallel-prefix-sum-fastest-implementation)? What have you tried?

Comment: If you read it properly the text you've clipped IS pseudo-code.

Comment: High Performance Mark:: I haven't understand the third step properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the provided answer is not enough to understand the algorithm, so I provided an actual answer with more comprehensive pseudocode here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12874227/697862 based on [Parallel Prefix Sum (Scan) with CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html) which is a complete article describing the optimum parallel algorithm according to:

> Blelloch, Guy E. 1990. "Prefix Sums and Their Applications." Technical
>   Report CMU-CS-90-190, School of Computer Science, Carnegie Mellon
>   University.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is pretty much pseudo-code on its own, but I hope this will help.

```
prefix_sum(List x):List
begin
   //This step is split in multiple tasks that are running in paralell
   //build z, be careful around the end
   w = prefix_sum(z)

   //This step should also be split in multiple tasks
   //build y, using w and x
   return y
end
```

EDIT: y<sub>i</sub> is desired sum we want to get, y<sub>i</sub> = w<sub>i/2</sub>, if i%2 == 1, and w<sub>i/2-1</sub>+<sub>x</sub>, otherwise. Here we assume, that w<sub>-1</sub>=0