# Getting rid of data dependency

Tags: parallel-processing

I have this code:

```
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    d[i] = d[i-1] + v[i];
}
```

When I do parallel processing for this loop, I have data dependency and the initiation interval becomes 2
Meaning I have:

initiation interval:2

```
|load v[i-1]|load d[i-2]|    add    |store d[i-1]|
|           |           |  load v[i]|load d[i-1] |     add    | store d[i] |
```

I do not want to stall in between.

initiation interval:1

```
|load v[i-1]|load d[i-2]|    add    |store d[i-1]|
|           |load v[i]  |load d[i-1]|     add    | store d[i] |
```

This is not possible since d[i-1] is not stored yet.

How do we make initiation interval to 1 by changing the code?

Comment: what language? It's quite hard to understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I'm asking how can I change the code to make the program not to stall. No specific language

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reduce that gap.

Also this (loop unrolling) is not the most efficient way of parallel processing for this kind of loop. Your loop looks like a prefix-sum operation. There are fast parallel algorithms and implementations available for prefix-sum. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053629/parallel-prefix-sum-fastest-implementation?lq=1)