# OPENMP : how to shuffle a vector in fortran

Tags: vector, fortran, openmp, shuffle

In my sequential code written in fortran, i have a subroutine to shuffle some vectors that works in this way:

```
    DO i=1,nsim

      IF(iflag(i) == 0)THEN

        j=j+1
        pos(j)=pos(i)
        v(j)=v(i)
        iflag(j)=iflag(i)

      END IF

    END DO
    nsim=j
```

I am a newbie OpenMP user so, i don't know how to write this loop in a correct way.
Initially, i thought something like this:

```
!$omp parallel do reduction(+: j)
  DO i=1,nsim

  IF(iflag(i) == 0)THEN

    j=j+1
    pos(j)=pos(i)
    v(j)=v(i)
    iflag(j)=iflag(i)

  END IF

END DO
!$omp end parallel do
nsim=j
```

But i don't know if in this way, i can produce a race condition. Any suggestions on how to write this loop better?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallelizing this kind of loop can be done by:

1. Using a "prefix-sum" operation over a sequence of ones and zeros, where the sequence element is 1 if the THEN is taken, and 0 otherwise. The result of the prefix-sum tells you the values of j for each iteration.
2. Do the THEN actions, with temporary arrays substituted for the left-hand sides,
   using the j values from step 1.
3. Copying the temporary arrays back to the original arrays.

See [discussion of parallel prefix-sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053629/parallel-prefix-sum-fastest-implementation) for details on implementing "prefix-sum".  Step 2 can be embedded in the "Downsweep" phase of the prefix-sum (see other discussion).  Because prefix-sum doubles bandwidth consumption (because it is a two-pass algorithm), getting speedup out of it is difficult.